Intermittent AWS RDS Connection Spikes Causing Production DB Outages
I'm new to AWS, and we're using a db.r7g.2xlarge instance running MySQL with default configurations. Typically, CPU usage and database connections are normal until "something" causes the DB connections to spike to the maximum, leading to our EC2 instances running out of threads (hitting MaxRequestWorkers in Apache settings).
We have one web app running on two EC2 instances, along with mobile apps and several batch jobs. Our tech stack includes Symfony 1.4 and Propel ORM 1.6. Interestingly, when the DB connections are maxed out, the CPU utilization remains consistent or drops, and there are no signs of database contentions or locking. Shouldn't the CPU usage spike due to the queries in those connections? Notably, all these connections appear idle.
I’d appreciate help in understanding this issue and any suggestions for a solution. Thank you! (We often have to reboot everything to restore service.)
Below, I've included the CloudWatch metrics from yesterday’s outage and the past week.
Matrix for First Outrage  : 28th June 2024 at 10.25 AM (PST)


Matrix for Second outrage: 28th June 2024  at 16:00


Matrix for Past 6 days


ELB matrix during the outrages.


